# How to create a custom project template in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-code

How can I create a template for new project in VS Code so that every time I create a new project from the template, every file and content of the file is automatically created for me. For example, I want VS Code to make my new project including a Makefile file with the following content:

```
console: main 
    ./main

file: main 
    ./main < input.txt > output.txt
    
main: main.cpp 
    g++ -g -O2 -std=gnu++17 -static main.cpp -o main
```

together with 3 files which are main.cpp, input.txt and output.txt.

Comment: Browse around the extensions to find something that suites you. I know I had one that this exactly this. Not sure what the name was though.

Comment: Did h ever find anything more recently  am looking more for a file new item experience

Answer (score 4):

I found the extension that is suitable for my needs. Its name is Project Templates.
Here is the link to the extension if anyone interested:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cantonios.project-templates.